# Why does JPanel not show its components until manually updated?

Tags: java, swing

I see Java Swing components like JFrame or JPanel having such weird property, that they don't display their components, unless they are activated by, for example clicking them.

And while in case of JFrame it can be solved simply by using the .pack() function, in case of JPanel it is literally hell.

I have tried .updateUI(), .validate(), .repaint() and even setting it firstly to wrong size to then resize. Nothing works.

Panel class:

```
package com.glowiak.xup.ui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class XupLoginPanel extends JPanel
{
    protected Image[] images;
    protected JTextField tf_username;
    protected JButton b_login;
    
    public XupLoginPanel()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16 * 50, 16 * 30));
        this.setLayout(null);
        
        this.loadImages();
        this.initComponents();
        this.updateOnResize();
    }
    private final void loadImages()
    {
        this.images = new Image[5];
        
        try {
            this.images[0] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/dirt.png"));
            this.images[0] = this.images[0].getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
            
            this.images[1] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/logo.png"));
            this.images[1] = this.images[1].getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
            
            this.images[2] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/favicon.png"));
        } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    private final void initComponents()
    {
        this.tf_username = new JTextField();
        this.b_login = new JButton("Play");
        
        this.add(this.tf_username);
        this.add(this.b_login);
    }
    protected final void updateOnResize()
    {
        this.tf_username.setBounds(this.getWidth() / 2 - 60, 160, 120, 25);
        this.b_login.setBounds(this.getWidth() / 2 - 60, 210, 120, 35);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        
        int tx = (int)(this.getWidth() / 32) + 2;
        int ty = (int)(this.getHeight() / 32) + 2;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tx; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ty; j++)
            {
                g.drawImage(this.images[0], i * 32, j * 32, null);
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(this.images[1], this.getWidth() / 2 - 256, 25, null);
        
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        tx = this.getWidth() / 2 - 80;
        ty = 130;
        int w = (this.getWidth() / 2 + 80) - tx;
        int h = 150;
        g.fillRect(tx, ty, w, h);
        
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Username:", tx + 45, ty + 20);
    }
}
```

window class:

```
package com.glowiak.xup.ui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import com.glowiak.xup.launcher.Launcher;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class XupWindow extends JFrame
{
    protected XupLoginPanel p_login;
    
    public Launcher launcher;
    
    public XupWindow()
    {
        super("Minecraft Launcher");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //this.setResizable(false);
        
        this.launcher = new Launcher();
        
        this.p_login = new XupLoginPanel();
        
        this.setIconImage(this.p_login.images[2]);
        
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                p_login.updateOnResize();
                p_login.validate();
                p_login.updateUI();
                p_login.repaint();
            }
        });
        
        this.add(this.p_login);
        
        this.pack();
        
        // an ugly fix because swing is so broken
        try { Thread.sleep(2); } catch (Exception e) {}
        this.setSize(16 * 50, 16 * 30);
        try { Thread.sleep(2); } catch (Exception e) {}
        this.p_login.validate();
        this.p_login.updateUI();
        this.p_login.repaint();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this.setLayout(null);](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)
*// an ugly fix because swing is so broken* It isn't broken. What *is* broken is *your code* as you are ignoring Swing's threading model

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent()` and not `paint()` for `JPanel `, don't subcalss `JFrame` , and you should be doing most of your computations outside of the EDT as possible, to name a few problems out of many.  Check out the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) and [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: 1) Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. 2) the updateOnSize() method is not needed. Use a proper layout manager and the size of components will automatically be resized based on the rules of the layout manager. 3) *an ugly fix because swing is so broken* - it is your code that is broken because of your lack of understanding how Swing works. Read the tutorials for examples showing a better way to structure your code and create the frame.

Comment: Move this.setVisible(true); at the end. This will make the frame visible after the required components have been added to it and you will see it without any click or resize.

Answer (score 3):

Override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`!

Basically the drawing of the images is being done at the wrong order: the button is being painted first, that is, the image are being draw over the button.

The `paint()` method calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder`, and `paintChildren` - drawing the *background* is better done in `paintComponent` so the component children are draw *over* the background.

---

Note: it is also recommended to use a `LayoutManager`, that is, do not do `setLayout(null)`!

Also have a look at the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial.